# What is the best word for possessive determiner his/her

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Is there any word or any rule that we can use instead of writing **his/her** all the time for possessive determiners

E.g: Student can come with **his/her** bag. - Student can come with **their** bag.

Is it grammatically correct if I can write **their** instead of **his/her**?

Comment: Yes, using *their* is grammatically correct, and perfectly expected here.

Comment: If you are learning English, you may find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) better suited to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Some schools of thought accept "Singular They," and some (like mine) do not. So it's not a matter of whether it's correct—it's a matter of whether it's correct according to your style guide, review board, grammatical philosophy, etc.

IMHO, the best method is to *avoid* the problem of gender by ***pluralizing the entire construction:*** "Students can come with their bags." Few circumstances don't allow that simple method. English singular pronouns diverge by gender; plural pronouns do not. So going plural removes gender from the equation.

For some while, it was common practice, when gender is not known, to use the male as generic: "A student can come with his bag," not meaning only a male student, but any student. But social values have become sensitive to this practice, and it is in wide disallowance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they